# Ambiguity of mean field approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-optics, many-body, mean-field-theory

I have a Condensed Matter Hamiltonian on some lattice (eg. square or triangular)
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{i,j}  :\hat{a}_j^\dagger \hat{a}_i \hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_j:   = \sum_{i,j}   \hat{a}_j^\dagger \hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_i  \hat{a}_j = \sum_{i,j} :B_{ij}^\dagger B_{ij}: = \sum_{i,j} B_{ij}^\dagger B_{ij} - \hat{n}_j 
\end{equation}

where $\hat{a}_i$ are bosonic ladder operators satisfying $[\hat{a}_i,\hat{a}_j^\dagger]= \delta_{ij}$
, "$: $ $:$" denotes the normal ordering operator, $\hat{n}$ is the number operator and I defined $B_{ij}= \hat{a}_i^\dagger \hat{a}_j$

I want to treat this with Mean field theory:
\begin{equation}
\Delta B_{ij} = B_{ij} -  ⟨B_{ij}⟩
\end{equation}

Now I have two options:
\begin{align}
H &= \sum_{i,j} B_{ij}^\dagger ⟨B_{ij}⟩+ ⟨B_{ij}^\dagger⟩  B_{ij} -⟨B_{ij}^\dagger⟩⟨B_{ij}⟩ + :\Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij}:\\
  &= \sum_{i,j} B_{ij}^\dagger ⟨B_{ij}⟩+ ⟨B_{ij}^\dagger⟩  B_{ij} -⟨B_{ij}^\dagger⟩⟨B_{ij}⟩ + \Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij} - \hat{n}_j 
\end{align}

Either I neglect the quadratic fluctuation term $:\Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij}:$ or  $ \Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij} $ which differ only by the normal ordering operator. The resulting Mean field Hamiltonian then differs by the term $- \sum_{i,j} \hat{n}_j $.

Now my question is: Can we generally say which approximation is better or in other words: which term gives the smaller correction?  The normal ordered quadratic fluctuations $:\Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij}:$ or  $ \Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij} $ ?

Edit:
As Anyon pointed out correctly the difference of the two theories will "only" result in an energy shift. I am however interested in the ground state energy, which is why I can not just throw away the constant term.

Comment: I'd say, for consistency, you should drop both. It would come to me as a surprise if they give much too different physical consequences

Comment: Hm, how could I drop both? $:\Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij}:$    $= \Delta B_{ij}^\dagger \Delta B_{ij} - n_j$. Dropping both would result in  $ n_j = 0$ which is clearly not true, right?

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely rigth. Sorry, I wasnt paying enough attention. Due to particle-hole symmetry, I think it doesn't matter which one you drop, or am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

Your Hamiltonian conserves particle number, so the number operator term will sum to a constant that you can throw away. Hence the two approximations are equivalent. One or the other may be preferable for aesthetic or practical (i.e. numerical accuracy) reasons, however.

Comment: You are right. But In my specific case I am actually interested in the ground state energy. I will edit the question. Thank you though.

Comment: @Benefisch Hmm. In a self-consistent numerical solution of the mean-field theory you can definitively keep the density term as-is (and again get equivalent formulations). Keeping constant terms is sometimes done in such calculations in order to compare the energy of different ansatzes for the order parameter.